# Providers/tools to support turn based code reviews

Tags: bitbucket, github-codereviews, jetbrains-space

jetbrains space introduced a concept that they call "turn based code reviews":
https://blog.jetbrains.com/space/2020/04/30/introducing-turn-based-code-reviews-in-space/

I really like it and it makes it much more efficient when you have to keep track of multiple PRs at a time.

Unfortunately it does not work this way in my git host (bitbucket). Does github support something similar or are there any other tools that facilitate a turn based workflow?

With normal PR reviews it is always kind of hard to see if my reaction is needed or if I still need to wait for someone else to do something.